# Fastest Way to Move Large Files on NAS

Tags: networking, windows-explorer, nas, file-transfer

Trying to reorganize my media on my NAS (ReadyNAS), and using windows explorer is extremely slow.

I've tried using the command:
`move "\\NAS\Documents\somepicfolder" "\\NAS\My Pics\somepicfolder"`
but get an `access denied` error. But before investigating that, wanted to make sure that this would be the fastest method.

**Side Question** (trying to understand what is actually happening):

When you move files on a local disk in Windows 10, it happens immediately. But on the NAS,is all that data going from the NAS, over the network, through the PC making the move request, back over the network to the NAS? Or is it simply updating the file allocation table on the NAS? If the latter, which is what I believe a local disc move does, why does it take so long in Windows Explorer.

**Main Question**:

What is the fastest way to do a move on a NAS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is all that data going from the NAS, over the network, through the PC making the move request, back over the network to the NAS?

Yes.

If you want to move your data (fast) you need to add SSH addon then login directly to ReadyNAS and use standard Unix's `mv` command.
There is a thread on netgear forum regarding this - how to use SSH on [ReadyNAS](https://community.netgear.com/t5/New-to-ReadyNAS/SSH-shell-He-says-quot-Let-there-be-colors-quot-Shell-Beginner/td-p/748047) that describes what you need to do.